# Is there any way through which I can make a specific item clickable in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, events, onitemclicklistener, selected

I have a scenario, where I am showing options in a ListView. But, for a special case, I need **only** last item of the ListView to be clickable. Is there any way I can achieve this??

adapter code:

```
    public class OptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OptionsPojo> {
    private int mColorResourceId;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
   OptionsPojo optionsPojo = getItem(position);

    View listItemView =  convertView;
    if (listItemView == null){
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.option_card, parent,false);
    }

    View textImgContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_img_text);
    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_text);

    ImageView icon = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView imgOptnText = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.option_text_view);
    TextView optionText = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    int color = getContext().getResources().getColor(mColorResourceId);

    if(optionsPojo.hasImage())
    {
        icon.setImageResource(optionsPojo.getmImageResourceId());
        textImgContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
        icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //setting option with image
        if (optionsPojo.getOption().startsWith("<p>"))
        {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                imgOptnText.setText(Html.fromHtml(optionsPojo.getOption(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
            else
                imgOptnText.setText(Html.fromHtml(optionsPojo.getOption()));
        }else
            imgOptnText.setText(optionsPojo.getOption());
    }else{
        textImgContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

        //setting option without image
        if (optionsPojo.getOption().startsWith("<p>"))
        {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                optionText.setText(Html.fromHtml(optionsPojo.getOption(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
            else
                optionText.setText(Html.fromHtml(optionsPojo.getOption()));
        }else
            optionText.setText(optionsPojo.getOption());
    }
    return listItemView;
}

public OptionAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<OptionsPojo> options, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context,0, options);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}
```

Activity code which is using listview:

```
      OptionAdapter Adapter = new OptionAdapter(this, optionList, R.color.background);
        listview.setAdapter(Adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                showDialog(ChosenTestQuestion.this,optionList.get(i).getAnswer());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes of course there are ways to achieve it. Please share your adapter of your `ListView`.

Comment: Create a click event for the entire listView and inside the event code check whether the currently selected item that was clicked was the last one of the list. If yes, do what you want, otherwise dont do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                if(i == (list.size()-1)){
                    showDialog(ChosenTestQuestion.this,optionList.get(i).getAnswer()); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and being kind, It worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have position variable in onItemClick method. You just need to check if this is your last element.